# Characterize the sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U,V$ be the following subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$

$U= \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3,a+b+c=0 \}$

$V=\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3,a=c  \} $

$W=\{(0,0,c)\in \mathbb R^3\}$

Carachterize :

a)$U+V$

I think of using new variables such as : $c=-a-b$ and then 
\begin{align}
& = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3 , c=-a-b\} \\U
& =\{(a,b,-a-b)\} \\
\end{align}

and V:
\begin{align}
V& = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3,a=c  \}                     \\
V& =\{c,b,c\}                      \\
\end{align}

And then $U+V$

$U+V=(-a-b,b,-a-b) $
What other option should i have consider?

b)$U+W$

I basically think the same as this example, to characterize means to me that i must consider the second vector constraint, to find the sum in this case.

$U+W=\{(0,0,-a-b)\}$ , c is still $-a-b$

I would appreciate guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $ U+V$ and $U+W$ are equal to $\mathbb R^{3}$. Note that $(1,0,-1)$ and $(1,-1,0)$ are linearly independent elmenets of $U$. $V$ contains $(1,0,1)$ and $W$ contains $(0,0,1)$. If you combine either of these with $\{(1,0,-1),(1,-1,0)\}$ you get three linearly independent elements. Hence $ U+V$ and $U+W$  both contain three linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Remark that

$x \in U+V \implies x=u+v=(a,b,-a-b)+(a,b,a)$ since $u\in U$ and $v\in V$